# Unexpected Token: int in processing

Tags: processing

So i'm writing a coloring/ art program and am trying to detect mouseclicks in a box to select color. I have color as a variable and I am using If statements to modify it, however my variable throws an error everytime i run it. the error arises from line 3 'int color = #FFFFFF'

```
void draw()
{
int color = #FFFFFF;
pen.beginDraw();
if(mousePressed && (mouseX > 5 && mouseX < 95 && mouseY > 5 && mouseY < 95))
{
pen.clear();
}
if(mousePressed && (mouseX > 5 && mouseX < 95 && mouseY > 105 && mouseY < 195))
{
color = #000000;
}
if(mousePressed && (mouseX >5 && mouseX <95 && mouseY > 205 && mouseY < 295))
{
color = #000EFF;
}
if(mousePressed && (mouseX >5 && mouseX <95 && mouseY > 305 && mouseY < 395))
{
color = #FF0000;
}
if(mousePressed && (mouseX >5 && mouseX <95 && mouseY > 405 && mouseY < 495))
{
color = #00FF0A;
println("green");
}
pen.fill(color);
pen.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
pen.endDraw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In processing the indent `color` is the name of a built-in function ([`color()`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html)), which creates a n integral color value from the red, green, blue and alpha color channels.
This causes that you can't declare a variable with the same name `color`.

You have to rename the variable to solve the issue:

e.g.

```java
int fillcolor = color(255);
```

```java
int fillcolor = color(0, 14, 255);
```

```java
int fillcolor = color(255, 0, 0, 255);
```

If you se the variable `fillcolor` by an hexadecimal value, then you have to set consider, that the color has an alpha channel too. This means the value consist of 4 color components and has to have 8 hexadecimal digits:

e.g.

```java
int fillcolor = #FFFFFFFF;
```

```java
int fillcolor = 0xFF000000;
```

Anyway it is to prefer to use the function [`color()`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html), which makes the code much more comprehensibly.

---

Probably you don't want to declare the variable in the function `draw`, but you want to declare a global variable.
Think about writing your code like this:

```java
int fillcolor = color(255);

void draw() {

    pen.beginDraw(); 

    if (mousePressed) {

        if (mouseX > 5 && mouseX < 95) {

            if (mouseY > 5 && mouseY < 95) {
                pen.clear();
            } else if (mouseY > 105 && mouseY < 195) {
                fillcolor = color(0);
            } else if (mouseY > 205 && mouseY < 295) {
                fillcolor = color(0, 0, 255);
            } else if (mouseY > 305 && mouseY < 395) {
                fillcolor = color(255, 0, 0);
            } else if (mouseY > 405 && mouseY < 495) {
                fillcolor = color(00, 255, 0);
                println("green");
            } 
        }
    }

    pen.fill(fillcolor);
    pen.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    pen.endDraw();
}
```

Comment: Okay so I've replaced my line `int color = #FFFFFF` with `color c = 0xFFFFFF` and replaced all my variables appropriately however its now showing an error in the console 'Exception in thread "thread-226"'  really appreciate your help with this

Comment: No, please read my answer. It has to be `int c = #FFFFFFFF;`. But you should use `int c = color(255, 255, 255);` or `int c = color(255);` in this case! Or even  `int c = color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);` if you want to use hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: okay thankyou so much, thats solved the problem, i think i was also having issues with corrupted files as ive just noticed that the hardrive i was storing the code on had fallen, unplugging itself, working great now, thankyou for all your help